# How to get pt-upgrade (Percona toolkit) to context switch on databases

Tags: mysql, automated-tests, percona

I am trying to use pt-upgrade from the Percona Toolkit to test running a load on a MySQL 5.1 and a MySQL 5.6 database server. I want to see if any queries I captured from a MySQL 5.1 slow log will fail on a MySQL 5.6 system. I read over the documentation at https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-upgrade.html and created the following command:

```
pt-upgrade h=IPADDRESS1 -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD  h=IPADDRESS2 uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD --type='slowlog' --max-class-size=1 --max-examples=1  --run-time=1m 'slow_log_mysqld.log' 1>report.txt 2>err.txt &
```

I restored a copy of all the databases where the slow log was taken onto two separate servers.

My command works fine and I've set it to only run for 1 minute for testing. The problem is all I see in the report is that queries fail on both hosts over and over again.

```
On both hosts:

DBD::mysql::st execute failed: No database selected [for Statement "....
```

It appears that pt-upgrade is not changing databases.

I've reviewed the slow query log and I clearly see statements like this before each SELECT statement:

```
  4                 9640337 Query   USE database1
  9                 9640337 Query   USE database2
```

I have over 100 hundred databases on the server where I got the slow log. Is there some limitation where pt-upgrade cannot switch between databases? How do I get pt-upgrade to work with multiple databases?

Comment: Have you tried specifying each database?: `pt-upgrade h=IPADDRESS1,D=database1 -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD  h=IPADDRESS2,D=database2 -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD ...`

Comment: If I specify a database it also complains about not being able to find the tables  because I have hundreds of databases. If I specify databases like the way you commented, I get this error:  * Only one or two DSNs can be specified; got 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something is odd with the format of the slow log on my system. 
I have to first "massage" my log with pt-query-digest before I can run pt-upgrade. Here is how I run the massage on my slow log using pt-query-digest:

```
pt-query-digest --filter '$event->{arg} =~ m/^select/i' --sample 5 --no-report --output slowlog mysql_slow.log > massaged_mysql_slow.log
```

Now I can run this:

```
pt-upgrade h=IPADDRESS1 -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD  h=IPADDRESS2 uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD --type='slowlog' --max-class-size=1 --max-examples=1  --run-time=1m 'massaged_mysql_slow.log' 1>report.txt 2>err.txt &
```